# how to call a function in a secondary thread with interval?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, nstimer

I am new to multi threading in xcode for iphone. i would like to load and parse data from server in another thread and periodically. Can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need threaded downloads? Most of the time runloop based asynchronous loading is a better solution. You can then still do the post-processing of that data on a different `NSOperationQueue` or `dispatch_queue_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use performSelector method, If need to have more clear idea navigate to this link [iPhone: how to use performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584394/iphone-how-to-use-performselectoronthreadwithobjectwaituntildone-method)

Answer (score 2):

You could use GCD event dispatch sources.
Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide includes a sample on [how to setup a timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW2).

Their sample code runs the block on the main queue. If you want it on a background thread, you could pass a queue obtained with [dispatch_get_global_queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_global_queue) instead of dispatch_get_main_queue().