# How do I create an NSThread that isn't the main thread without performing a selector immediately

Tags: ios, nsthread

I want to create a worker thread that isn't the main thread so I can call ...

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doStuff) OnThread:self.myWorkerThread withObject:nil];
```

... in a bunch of locations in my code. How do I create a thread.. any thread and assign it to a variable so I can use it over and over in my code. NSThread detachNewThreadWithSElector will only create one for the purpose of running that one selector. I need to create a thread and use it somehow.

I am using iOS and need to perform all my CoreData writes on a writerThread. I need to use the same thread (that isn't the main one) every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend looking into Grand Central Dispatch instead :).  You can easily create a dispatch queue via dispatch_queue_create or get one of the existing concurrent threads and send whatever you want to it.  It will create the appropriate number of threads based on the workload / OS status, etc.  It will look like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //Do stuff
});
```

Or you can look into its NS counterpart, NSOperation.  I don't know of a way to do this with just NSThread.  It seems the only way to set its selector is to init it with one.

**EDIT**
If you want just a thread, just call `[[NSThread alloc] init]` :p

**FURTHER EDIT:**
[iPhone: how to use performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584394/iphone-how-to-use-performselectoronthreadwithobjectwaituntildone-method)

As per this answer, it is going to be difficult to set up, as every thread needs a "main" function at the time it is created or else it will do nothing...

Comment: if I performSelectorWithThread:[NSThread mainThread] it works fine but performSelectorWithThread:[[NSThread alloc] init] freezes and doesn't do anything :(.. I tried calling 'start' after allocing it but it does nothing.

Comment: Apologies: I am frustrated by the extreme lack of documentation. I should not have taken it out here. comment removed.

Comment: No problem.  It's a common frustration to have.  If you have an active question about it though maybe I can help answer it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the easiest way would be to use blocks:

```
void (^now)(void) = ^ {
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"The date and time is %@", date);
};
```

and call:

```
now();
```

NSBlockOperation or dispatch_async().

See more here: http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1

Comment: I'm on iOS... aren't they mac only?

Comment: No blocks are used on iOS.  What SDK are you using?  They are supported in 4 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want this and not using GCD, then:

```
NSThread *thr = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:anobject selector:@selector(doStuff) object:nil];
```

And this will call the appropriate method on your object whenever you want - however, it seems to me that the current implementation of NSThread doesn't permit to change the target and selector.

Comment: Thats backwards to what I want. Periodically I write to core data and I want to do this on a designated thread (on startup) so I don't have to have multiple NSManagedObjectContexts. so I need to performSelectOnThread:<previously designated thread>

Comment: missing:   [thr start];
:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically doing this to interact with Core Data (as your question suggests), and you can require iOS 5 for your app, you might want to investigate the new private queue managed object context added in iOS 5. It creates and manages the thread/dispatch queue for you, and you send it blocks to run on the queue as a way of interacting with it. See [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/) and the [WWDC session video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/303/) for more details.

**Update** (May 2016): the new API added in iOS 5 was `-[NSManagedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:]`. As of iOS 9, the older initializer has been deprecated, along with the confinement concurrency type that had been the default prior to the introduction of the queue-based concurrency types. So if you're not using queues to manage context access, I'd strongly recommend moving in that direction.

I'd also strongly recommend [using the `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` launch argument](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/) while you're developing, in order to help you catch places where you're breaking the rules.

Comment: Link is dead - this is why you should include some content from the link in your answer.