# Preload circle for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, preloader

I search for a lot forums but nothing found, my problem is that

> I need preload some data from the web to load to the UITableView.

I saw some apps solved this problem, when show UITableView they shows "**waiting circle**" as modal view and after data is loaded just hide this circle.

1. Is there simple solution to do this?
2. What I need to do?
3. What kind of Request do I need: synchronius or asynchronius?
4. How to show this circle, do I need to show animatedGif or there is some internal/external control for this?

Comment: That waiting circle is called Activity Indicator...

Comment: @ Luft: you cant use gif image in iPhone. iPhone not allow gif images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a NSThread  for your "waiting circle"-(Activity Indicator).

1)Threads [How do I create an NSThread that isn't the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936267/how-do-i-create-an-nsthread-that-isnt-the-main-thread-without-performing-a-sele).

2)Activity Indicator [How to use activity indicator view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593234/how-to-use-activity-indicator-view-on-iphone).

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)showWaitingView {

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(90, 190, 32, 32);
UIActivityIndicatorView* progressInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[progressInd startAnimating];
progressInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;

frame = CGRectMake(130, 193, 140, 30);
UILabel *waitingLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
waitingLable.text = @"Processing...";
waitingLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
waitingLable.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];;
waitingLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
theView.alpha = 0.7;
theView.tag = 999;
[theView addSubview:progressInd];
[theView addSubview:waitingLable];

[progressInd release];
[waitingLable release];

[window addSubview:[theView autorelease]];
[window bringSubviewToFront:theView];
[pool drain];
  }

 - (void)removeWaitingView {
UIView *v = [window viewWithTag:999];
if(v) [v removeFromSuperview];

}
```