# How can I ensure that NSOperationQueue uses only one thread?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, nsoperationqueue, abaddressbook

`ABAddressBookRef` can only be accessed by one thread. I think a good model would be having a thread for `ABAddressBookRef` in the background, besides the main thread.

How can I ensure that there's only one thread while using `NSOperationQueue`? Simply setting max concurrency to 1 won't guarantee it to be run on the same thread.

Should I use other unique threads like web threads?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create a thread and redirect all address book access to it.

You **create a thread** with something like this ([adapted from documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)):

```
NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:[MyThread new]
                                    selector:@selector(myThreadMainMethod)
                                    object:nil];
[myThread start];  // Actually create the thread
```

Note that for the thread to be useful, you have to **implement a run loop** in thread's main method.

[See example implementation of run loop in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615480/115200).

You are then able to **do stuff on this thread** using the `NSObject`'s method `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.

Here's a wrapper library for `ABAddressBookRef` that implements this concept – [**RHAddressBook**](https://github.com/heardrwt/RHAddressBook/blob/master/RHAddressBook/RHAddressBook.m).

Comment: I don't believe the linked license allows that without a lot of boilerplate. I'll add some code examples, not directly copied from the link.