# performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: doesn't execute my function

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

I have a function:

```
-(void)doTask{
 NSLog(@"do task start.");
...
}
```

I want to run this function on another thread, this is what I tried:

```
NSThread *workerThread = [[NSThread alloc] init];
[workerThread start];

[self performSelector:@selector(doTask)
             onThread:workerThread
           withObject:nil
        waitUntilDone:NO];
```

when I run it, the `doTask` function is not executed. WHY?

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2584394/6541007) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `selector` to run when the thread starts:

```
NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(myThreadMainMethod:)
                                               object:nil];
[myThread start];  // Actually create the thread
```

And:

```
- (void)myThreadMainMethod:(id)object {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"do task start; object = %@", object);
    }
}
```

Please refer to the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2).

---

For what it's worth, you probably should be using Grand Central Dispatch or operation queues, as it makes threading much easier. See the [Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) section of the *Concurrency Programming Guide.*

Comment: Yes, this works, I know, but I am wondering how can I make it work with my code? Actually, I was using this code before, now for complex reason, I need to create thread & start first , then perform selector on the started thread. Is it possible?

Comment: See [Setting Up a Run Loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW25) and [When Would I Use a Run Loop?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW24).